# Using grep for the output of a command

Tags: linux, bash, centos, grep

grep might not be the solution to what I need. I'm trying to grab the MB/s info from this command `dd if=/dev/zero of=tempfile bs=1M count=1024`
which returns the following information 
`1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
xamount bytes(1.1GB) copied, 11.234 s, 30.5 MB/s`

what I tried was `dd if=/dev/zero of=tempfile bs=1M count=1024|grep -oP '.....MB/s`
but I'm fairly new to the grep command and I'm sure I'm doing it wrong. also this is on centOS

Comment: @steeldriver thank you, that's what I needed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to grab the part containing the number and `MB/s` (or `GB/s`), you could use

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=tempfile bs=1M count=1024 2>&1 | grep -o '[0-9.]\+ .B/s$'
```

You need to redirect stderr to stdout, because `dd` writes this information to stderr.

Answer (score 0):

with awk

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=tempfile bs=1M count=1024 |awk 'END{print $(NF-1)" "$NF}'
```